# how to access an array in an array in json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, web

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();



{
"name":"John",
"age":31,
"pets":[
    { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
    { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
    { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
]}
```

how do i reference the values in the pets array. as shown above i can reference the the name value but when ever i try to reference the values of animal inside pets. it returns just [object Object]

Comment: Well you need to `stringify`.

Comment: _array in array_....title does not match the actual issue.

Comment: myObj.pets[ 0 ].name should return Fido.

Comment: @CodeManiac No. OP needs to iterate through the objects in the array.

Comment: @code maniac How pls??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop the "pets".Like

```
  var dataArry = {
           "name":"John",
           "age":31,
           "pets":[
             { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
             { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
             { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
        ]}


   dataArry.pets.forEach(function(eachPet) {
        console.log(eachPet);
    });
```

You need to use foreach function.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hope this will fix your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myObj.pets.map(function(item){ console.log(item) })
```

this will give you the following result:

{animal: "dog", name: "Fido"}

{animal: "cat", name: "Felix"}

{animal: "hamster", name: "Lightning"}

to access single animal's name use

```
myObj.pets.map(function(item){ console.log(item.name); })
```

to get animal use:

```
myObj.pets.map(function(item){ console.log(item.animal); })
```

Another option is to use:

```
for(var pet of myObj.pets)
{
  console.log(pet.animal); //for animal
  console.log(pet.name); //for name
}
```

Comment: Your solution requires do create a completely new array. You'e not using OP's data.

Comment: Yes edited my answer and written comment to mention that this is for example.Kindly edit it accordingly if i am still wrong.I am new and trying to contribute

Comment: @Devinder please do the edits. as suggested by CodeF0x.

Comment: @Devinder please see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
myObj.pets.forEach(function (pet) {
    console.log(pet); // What you need is probably *pet.name*
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    var pets= myObj.pets;
    for(var i=0;i<pets.length;i++){
        console.log(pets[i].name);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access like this *edit: with [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) *

```
        var person = {
        "name":"John",
        "age":31,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
            { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
        ]};

        $.each(person.pets,function (k,v) {
            console.log(v.animal, v.name);
        });
```

Comment: Ehh ... jQuery is not tagged nor included in OP's code, why to answer with jQuery then? The task at hands seems to be pretty trivial, an enormous library is not needed to solve the problem.